# How to unbold colorbar labels in a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, seaborn, heatmap

I have the following code which creates a heatmap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load dataset from seaborn
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights = flights.pivot('month', 'year', 'passengers')

# Plot heatmap
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar_kws={'label': 'Passenger Numbers'})

# Rotate x-axis labels
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# Set font size for colorbar title
ax1.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(12)
# Set font size for colorbar labels
ax1.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=10)

# Set font for x-axis labels
plt.xticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')
# Set font for y-axis labels
plt.yticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')

# Bold 'February' in y-axis
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if label.get_text() == 'February':
        label.set_weight('bold')

plt.show()
```

The heatmap looks like this:
[image: heatmap]

How do I unbold the colorbar labels (ie. the 600, 500, 400 values in the colorbar etc.) so that it is unbolded and similar to how the years (in the x-axis) and the months (in the y-axis, except for February) are displayed?

Many thanks in advance to anyone who knows this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The colorbar labels are not bold for me. What versions of seaborn/matplotlib are you using? Also how are you running the code?

Comment: Using seaborn version 0.10.1 and matplotlib version 3.1.3. I am using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the style in the firtsly, and then do the changes, you can try something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
#Create the style of the font 
font = {'family' : 'serif',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 10}         

matplotlib.rc('font', **font) #set the font style created
# Load dataset from seaborn
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights = flights.pivot('month', 'year', 'passengers')

# Plot heatmap
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar_kws={'label': 'Passenger Numbers'})

# Rotate x-axis labels
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# Set font size for colorbar title
ax1.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(12)
# Set font size for colorbar labels
ax1.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=10)

# Set font for x-axis labels
plt.xticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')
# Set font for y-axis labels
plt.yticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')

# Bold 'February' in y-axis
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if label.get_text() == 'February':
        label.set_weight('bold')

plt.show()
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to update params of the style, before styling the x,y axis. You can try this by adding `plt.rcParams.update({'font.weight': 'normal'})` before the `# Set font size for colorbar title`. You can see the posible fonts [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo.html).

Comment: Thanks @MrNobody33. I tried this but it's not working. The colorbar labels are still bolded and I am getting this error message `findfont: Font family ['normal'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.`

Comment: I just edited my answer, the variable font changed: `'family' : 'serif'`. If it doesn't work, try the last thing `plt.rcParams.update({'font.weight': 'normal'}) `

Comment: Or you can try with `font = {'family' : 'DejaVu Sans', 'weight' : 'normal', 'size'   : 10} `

Comment: Thanks @MrNobody33! I can confirm changing to `'family' : 'serif'` worked! This is a really strange way (for me at least) of setting the fonts at the beginning first. I don't see many people code like this before

Comment: FYI, setting `'family' : 'DejaVu Sans'` bolds everything, so this doesn't work. Do you know what other `family` types I can try besides `serif`?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want that, you can also use the last thing I write in my answer, `plt.rcParams.update({'font.weight': 'normal'})`. I still find weird that your colorbar labels are bold, because I run the original script in Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda, with the same versions of seaborn/matplotlib, and the colorbar labels are not bold for me, like @DavidG. Anyways, good thing it worked out for you.

Comment: @Leockl yeah, read my answer, I attach a link with the possible font styles at the end of my answer. Checkout it.

Comment: Many thanks @MrNobody33, yeah it's good that it worked for me! Ok thank you for the link, will have a look.